# How to know if username already exists in database?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Dim okToadd As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to add the current record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
    If okToadd = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        MsgBox("Admin information Added Sucessfully", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)

        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        'Change the following to your access database location
        dataFile = "C:\Users\talha\Documents\login.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString

        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "insert into loginusers ([username], [password], [firstname], [lastname]) values (?, ?, ?, ?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)


        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("username", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("password", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("firstname", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("lastname", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))







        Try

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
            TextBox3.Clear()
            TextBox4.Clear()
            DataGridView1.Refresh()

        Catch ex As Exception
            DataGridView1.Refresh()
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            DataGridView1.Refresh()
        End Try
    ElseIf okToadd = MsgBoxResult.No Then

    End If
```

Comment: First, you shouldn't display a "success" messagebox before you even try to do the insert, what happens if the insert fails and you've already told the user it worked? Second, there is no Merge SQL function for access DBs, so you will need to either add a query to check if the username already exists and only insert if it doesn't or you need to make username the table's primary key and put your insert in a try-catch that will read a primary-key constraint violation

Answer (score 1):

You can designate username field as Primary Key in your database.

Comment: please tell me in details